# const variable Are Local to a File By Default

Tags: c++

In C++ Primer (4th edition) there is a section as follows:

Unlike other variables, unless otherwise specified, `const` variables declared at global scope are
local to the file in which the object is defined. The variable exists in that file only and cannot be
accessed by other files.
We can make a `const` object accessible throughout the program by specifying that it is `extern`:

```
// file_1.cc

// defines and initializes a const that is accessible to other files   

extern const int bufSize = fcn();

// file_2.cc
extern const int bufSize; // uses bufSize from file_1

// uses bufSize defined in file_1

for (int index = 0; index != bufSize; ++index)

      // ...
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
  // file_1.cc
  // defines and initializes a const that is accessible to other files
  const int bufSize = fcn();
  // file_2.cc
  extern const int bufSize; // uses bufSize from file_1
  // uses bufSize defined in file_1
  for (int index = 0; index != bufSize; ++index)
        // ...
```

It also has no problem. So my question is that:

Is `const` variable local to the file or is this just a mistake?

Thanks very much.

Comment: "I have try like this [...] It is also no problem." Which compiler? I do get the linker error that you seem to be expecting.

Comment: This paragraph of the book is always raising questions for me too, perhaps they should have saved it for later, when explaining the linkage directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, constant values default to external linkage, so they can appear only in source files. In C++, constant values default to internal linkage, which allows them to appear in header files.

When you declare a variable as const in a C source code file, you do so as:

```
const int i = 2;
```

You can then use this variable in another module as follows:

```
extern const int i;
```

But to get the same behavior in C++, you must declare your const variable as:

```
extern const int i = 2;
```

If you wish to declare an extern variable in a C++ source code file for use in a C source code file, use:

```
extern "C" const int x=10;
```

to prevent name mangling by the C++ compiler.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Yes,you are right.Thanks very much.I have made a mistake that i declare variable in C source code file .So I can use it even the variable is declare like const int i = 2.And i have try it again that it correspond as you say.At last,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `extern` is just a declaration, whether or not the variable is `const` or not.

The `const` implies **internal linkage** though. You can think of it as a

```
static int x;
```

at global scope which you can't modify. If by "local to a file" you mean internal linkage, then yes, that's correct.